# Rake Execute With Multiple Arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm calling a rake task within a task and I'm running into a roadblock when it comes to calling execute

```
response = Rake::Task["stuff:sample"].execute[:match => "HELLO"]
```

or

```
response = Rake::Task["stuff:sample"].execute[:match => "HELLO",:freq=>'100']
```

Calling task

```
task :sample, [:match,:freq] => :environment  do |t, args|
```

The error I get back is 'can't convert Hash into Integer'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is in code you're not posting.  Works fine for me:

```
james@James-Moores-iMac:/tmp$ head r.rb call.rb 
==> r.rb <==
task :sample, [:match,:freq] do |t, args|
  puts "hello world"
  puts args[:match]
end

==> call.rb <==
require 'rubygems'
require 'rake'
load 'r.rb'
Rake::Task["sample"].execute :match => "HELLO"
james@James-Moores-iMac:/tmp$ ruby call.rb 
hello world
HELLO
james@James-Moores-iMac:/tmp$
```

Answer (score 4):

The square brackets in your execute syntax confuse me.  Is that a special rake syntax (that you may be using incorrectly) or do you mean to send an array with one element (a hash)? 
Isn't it the same as this?

```
response = Rake::Task["sample"].execute([:match => "HELLO",:freq=>'100'])
```

Beyond that, `Task#execute` expects Rake:TaskArguments.

```
class TaskArguments
    ...

    # Create a TaskArgument object with a list of named arguments
    # (given by :names) and a set of associated values (given by
    # :values).  :parent is the parent argument object.
    def initialize(names, values, parent=nil)
```

You could use:

```
stuff_args = {:match => "HELLO", :freq => '100' }
Rake::Task["stuff:sample"].execute(Rake::TaskArguments.new(stuff_args.keys, stuff_args.values))
```

You could also use Task#invoke, which will receive basic args.  Make sure you `Task#reenable` if you invoke it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

This post is pretty old but I found the first answer is wrong by passing a hash inside an array. We can send arguments by passing them as a hash as following

```
response = Rake::Task["sample"].execute(match: "HELLO", freq: 100)
```

Inside the rake task, we can access them in args as `args[:match]` and `args[:freq].to_i`